# Três diferentes comentários de ajuda a uma resposta mal formulada

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, respostas

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51243/7210) a esta pergunta [Visualizar dados de banco Oracle via MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44468/visualizar-dados-de-banco-oracle-via-mysql) tinhamos 3 diferentes comentários de ajuda ao AR (Autor da Resposta):

> Se tiver uma nova pergunta, faça-a clicando no botão Fazer pergunta. Inclua um link para esta pergunta se ajudar a fornecer contexto.

---

> Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele - você sempre pode comentar em suas próprias publicações e quando tiver pontos de reputação suficientes você poderá comentar sobre qualquer publicação.

A meu ver, o que melhor se encaixa na resposta é este comentário:

> Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência. As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada.

Como proceder nestes casos que podem levar a que o AR  fique confuso?

Comment: Sempre tenho essa dúvida. Quando vejo que já possui um comentário, apenas recomendo a exclusão, sem comentário, para não confundir o AR.

Answer (score 2):

Simples, devemos orientá-lo de forma mais específica. Não sei se eu consegui orientar bem mas tentei.

[Visualizar dados de banco Oracle via MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44468/visualizar-dados-de-banco-oracle-via-mysql#comment104217_51243)

Eu realmente não sei bem qual foi a intenção dele. Minha primeira avaliação é que ele achou algo que ajudou no problemas mas agora precisa de uma nova ajuda. No fundo acho que a pergunta dele deveria ser editada mas como não tinha esta opção, fui na "nova pergunta". Provavelmente deveria ter escolhido um comentário personalizado.

Podemos sinalizar para um moderador apagar os demais comentários.

Comment: Isso foi a tua interpretação, o problema aqui é que temos 3 interpretações diferentes. "orientá-lo de forma mais específica" parece-me óbvio, mas mesmo assim já são 4 comentários a tentar ajudar. Até para mim se torna um bocadinho confuso...

Comment: @JorgeB. adicionei mais uma ação. Mas é preciso resolver a questão de ter 3 ações semi-conflitantes. Enquanto nada mais possa ser feito, é preciso deixar claro para ele porque aquilo está acontecendo.

Comment: Poderá ser um solução: `comentar para esclarecer` + `sinalizar os restantes comentários`

Comment: Deixei só o seu último comentário lá para que fique menos confuso. E concordo com a orientação de sinalizar os comentários quando discordarem. De preferência, usem o motivo "outros" e expliquem a situação, pois o sistema de moderação de comentários não é lá essas coisas.

Comment: Parece que afinal é um comentário: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44468/visualizar-dados-de-banco-oracle-via-mysql#comment104232_51243

Comment: @JorgeB. ainda discordamos, acho que é uma edição :) Um comentário poderia ser também. Mas uma edição sempre é melhor que um comentário.

Comment: Sim, eu só copiei o que disse o AR ;)

Comment: O problema lá é bem maior: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44468/visualizar-dados-de-banco-oracle-via-mysql/51243?noredirect=1#comment104257_51243

Comment: São duas contas não registadas... Nem sei bem como isso funciona. Já tinha reparado, mas acho que isso já foi discutido no meta, não sei é onde.